# Gson java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, gson

I am getting  `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error when i am using android.jar and gson jar in my java project. I am getting error in below line

```
Type typeOfReultClass = new TypeToken<URLDataResponse>() {}.getType();
```

And below logcat error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26480): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kony.andffiJS.DownloadActivity$3
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at com.kony.andffiJS.DownloadActivity.downloadData(DownloadActivity.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at com.kony.andffiJS.DownloadActivity.access$2(DownloadActivity.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at com.kony.andffiJS.DownloadActivity$1.onClick(DownloadActivity.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
E/AndroidRuntime(26480):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you recently updated your sdk or adt?

Comment: No. but my adt version is 22.

Comment: `new TypeToken() {}` creates an anonymous (`..$3`) subclass of `TypeToken` as an inner class of `DownloadActivity`. If that class definition is not found it would probably mean that `TypeToken` could not be found. Try cleaning the project & check that the library that includes `TypeToken` is *exported* (= contained in the resulting jar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps:

1. Remove all Android Library projects and external jars from the build
   path.
2. Create a folder named 'libs' in your project.
3. Place all external .jars in that folder, the ADT should now place them under
   'Android Dependencies'.
4. Re-import all your previous Android Library projects the normal way.

The issue is that external jars are not placed in the 'libs' folder by default when using Properties - Java
    Build Path- Add External Jar, instead they are placed under
    'Referenced Libraries' instead of 'Android Dependencies' and this
    causes the NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: But i am not working on Android Project, I am using android.jar in my project so no Android Dependencies folder will generated.